# Associate .txt files with VB.NET Program

Tags: vb.net, associate

I created a super `basic text editor` which can read **`.txt`** files. I would like to know how I can set my basic text editor to the default .txt file extension so whenever the user clicks on a .txt file, at first it will show the "default program" window. If the user clicks on my program then the text files will be always opened using my program. How can this be done?

Comment: Shouldn't the end user decide that?

Comment: Yes. It's ultimately up to the user but by default my program should be able to open .txt files. E.g. If there is a text file in the documents folder, when the user clicks on the file, at first it will open the default text editor and when it does that it will bring up a window saying what do you want to set as default. Let's say the user clicks on my program, then the next time he clicks on the text file, my program should open up with the text file loaded.

Comment: To begin with, your program must be capable of receiving a file name from the command line and be able to open that file as if the user would use the "open" menu (or your equivalent). Command line parameters are the standard way Windows uses to open files with specific programs.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your version of windows, but in Windows 7/Vista you can click Start->Default programs

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-default-programs#1TC=windows-7

In Windows XP it's a little more difficult:

1. Go to the Start menu and select All Programs.
2. Select Set Program Access and Defaults.
3. To select an option, click on the radio button beside it.
4. If you need to expand the option, click on the double arrows for that option on the right side of the window.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/332003

If you want to do this programatically, you have to edit some registry settings. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx