# VB.NET - Edit Windows Registry Value

Tags: vb.net, registry, edit

I'm trying to set my program as the **`"Default Program"`** for all **`Text Files`** so in order to do this I need to change the **`(Default)`** value which is: *%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1* to *C:\Program.exe %1* in **`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\open\command\`**

I do this by using this code:

```
        Dim regKey As RegistryKey
        regKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("txtfile\shell\open\command", True)
        regKey.SetValue("(Default)", "C:\Program.exe %1", RegistryValueKind.ExpandString)
        regKey.Close()
```

The problem is that when I do it, it creates another key with the Expand String called "(Default)" rather than editing the "(Default)" key which is already there. How can I ***EDIT*** rather than just create?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Associate .txt files with VB.NET Program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306011/associate-txt-files-with-vb-net-program)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explicitly mentioned in a **NOTE** in the MSDN article for [`RegistryKey.SetValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k23f0345(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A registry key can have one value that is not associated with any name. When this unnamed value is displayed in the registry editor, the string "(Default)" appears instead of a name. To set this unnamed value, specify either null or the empty string ("") for the name.

Fix:

```
    regKey.SetValue("", "C:\Program.exe %1", RegistryValueKind.ExpandString)
```